# How to write lines to a file with the last line without linebreak?

Tags: python, text, output

I am writing a list of strings to a text file in Python for Windows 10.

What I tried at first is

```
with open('filename1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in list1:
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n')
```

The problem is the output file has a linebreak at the end of the file.

The next thing I tried is

```
with open('filename1.txt', 'w') as f:
    for line in list1[:-1]:
        f.write(line)
        f.write('\n')
    f.write(list1[-1])
```

This method works, but I believe there must be a more elegant way to achieve this.
Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Options include:

- Wrap the code in a function, so that you only have to worry about this line-writing algorithm once. Of course, you're still slicing the list, which is memory-inefficient.
- Join the strings with newlines ahead of time; `'\n'.join(list1)` will not have a trailing newline, so it implicitly solves the problem. This is also memory inefficient, since you create that string in memory.
- Invert the logic - instead of putting a newline after each line but the last, we can put one before each line but the first. It's easier to know which line is first while we're iterating through them, than which is last; this way, we don't need to slice - we can use flag logic instead. Thus:

```
with open('filename1.txt', 'w') as f:
    started = False
    for line in list1:
        if started:
            f.write('\n')
        started = True
        f.write(line)
```

(Of course, I would still make a function for that.)

- Simplify the above logic by directly storing a value to write before each line, instead of an explicit flag. That is: the first time around we write `''` before the line (no net effect), and each subsequent time we write `'\n'`. Thus:

```
with open('filename1.txt', 'w') as f:
    before = ''
    for line in list1:
        f.write(before)
        before = '\n' # impacts every line except the first
        f.write(line)
```

(Of course, I would *still* make a function for *that*.)

Comment: Or, let the flag be empty or contain a newline. `sep = ''; for line in list1: f.write(sep); sep = '\n'; f.write(line)`. No repeated conditions to check, just a single no-op write.

Comment: That is a good enough idea that I saw fit to edit it in.

Comment: I should admit that the call to `f.write` is probably slower than the boolean check, but I also love getting rid of a level of indentation where possible (and the I/O probably dwarfs the cost of the function call anyway).

Comment: Python's file objects (like in many other languages) are buffered by default. In my testing, `f.write('')` takes maybe a few hundred CPU cycles, even with all of Python's overhead. It writes to memory, and since nothing is actually written, the buffer can't fill and it won't actually trigger a disk write.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
f.write('\n'.join(list1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Julien's answer is the simplest and most elegant, but it means creating the whole file output in memory. You didn't say whether that would be OK or not, so if it is, go for their solution.

If you want to avoid that temporary copy, I would use an explicit iterator to first print the initial line, and then output a newline before each subsequent line:

```
with open('filename1.txt', 'w') as f:
    my_iter = iter(list1)  
    f.write(next(my_iter, ''))
    for line in my_iter:
        f.write('\n')
        f.write(line)
```

It may not look like more elegant code, but it's avoiding any additional temporary copy of the list, before or after formatting.

Comment: The `iter` approach is quite elegant. I think people are often resistant to this sort of thing on the grounds of `Simple is better than complex` - but complexity is to a large extent in the eye of the beholder.